# What is the difference between System.Int32 and int and why does getType() evaluate the same value once to this and once to the other?

Tags: powershell, types

This is a simple function that I can pass a value to. The function will
evaluate `getType()` on the value and print it:

```
function showTypeOfParam($p) {
  write-host $("Type of $p is " + $p.getType())
  write-host $p.getType()
}
```

If I call the function like so:

```
showTypeOfParam   1
```

it will print

```
Type of 1 is int
System.Int32
```

What is the difference between `int` and `System.Int32`?
And why does it once print `int` and once `System.Int32`?

Comment: On some Systems `int` may not be a 32bit integer. `Int32` is guranteed to be one.

Comment: I understand that, but why does the script print int once and Int32 the other time?

Comment: Maybe, because it is the same on your machine and getType not returning a String there may be a difference between `""+$p.getType()` and the String you get by writing `$p.getType()` to the console

Comment: what you are seeing is the way that the powershell display system auto-string-ifies that type. they are both the same _effective_ type. ///// the conversion you are seeing is because the way you built the string lets the display system choose the exact way the type is represented. ///// if you go digging you will find that the `::MaxValue` for each is the same. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

The underlying type is the same, but when you pass an object to the Write-Host `-Object` parameter, somewhere along the way the `ToString()` method is called on the object, which results in `System.Int32`.

```
> Write-Host (1).GetType()
System.Int32

> (1).GetType().ToString()
System.Int32
```

When you use the addition operator on a string, to object is first type cast to a string, which results in `int`:

```
> "" + (1).GetType()
int

> "$((1).GetType())"
int

> [String](1).GetType()
int
```

The same thing happens when you pass the type to a String parameter (due to the type cast):

```
> Write-Verbose -Message (1).GetType() -Verbose
VERBOSE: int
```

**Note**: The object is actually a `System.RuntimeType`, due to the use of the `GetType()` method.